# How to get the names of days between two dates ionic+angularjs

Tags: ionic-framework

After using this function to get the number of days I want to get the names of days between two dates ionic+angularjs.

```js
$scope.dayDiff = function (date1, date2) {
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
  $scope.dayDifference = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  alert($scope.dayDifference);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I did it. [View Plunkr Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xo9AoougTd0xbhd4j1Q1?p=preview)

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var days = function(date1, date2) {
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diff = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    var _days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var days = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
      date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + i);
      days.push(_days[date1.getDay()]);
    }
    return days;
  };

  $scope.days = days(new Date(2016, 05, 01), new Date(2016, 05, 05));

})
```